# How to make the content adapt to the screen when the Sidenav opens (Im Using Angular 5)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

**Problem:** 
Hello world, I'm using Angular 5 with Angular Material. What I have been fighting for days and I can not do is that when the Sidenav or Sidebar is opened (as you want to call it), the content leave the screen. I want it to adapt to the content, instead of leaving.

**A gif is worth a thousand words:**
[image]

**app.header-component.html**

```html
<!--- Toolbar starts here-->
<div class="container-toolbar">
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="fixed-header">

<button
type="button"
aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
mat-icon-button
(click)="drawer.toggle()">
<mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
</button>
<span class="spacer"></span>
<button type="button" mat-icon-button href="">
<mat-icon matTooltip="Salir">exit_to_app</mat-icon>
</button>


</mat-toolbar>
</div>

<!--- Sidenav starts here -->
<mat-sidenav-container style="height:100%;width:100%;">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'side' : 'push'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async)" style="box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #999;z-index: 2;">
     <mat-nav-list>
<app-tabs-nav></app-tabs-nav>
  </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="app-body">


  <main class="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
      <ngx-loading [show]="loading"></ngx-loading>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Could someone tell me where to start to look for the solution? I have already tried many things and I am somewhat blocked, thanks!

Comment: a minimal stackblitz would make it easier to help you...

Comment: I cannot import the project to a Stackblitz because have a lot of Modules, but, I can edit and put more code maybe if somebody need